# is there any file upload library/third-part application in django?

Tags: django, upload

is there any library or open-source application with the feature:

upload images/files from browser
upload images/files from a url (download the content and store it)
rich user interface like upload progress bar or file manager etc.

and any other help or suggestion?

I want do an application let user upload picture from there computer or just enter an url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[django-filebrowser](http://code.google.com/p/django-filebrowser/) is very nice, although it doesn't meet all your requirements (it doesn't have a progress bar, for example).

Answer (score 1):

I used django-filebrowser and am happy with it.  You could customise the code to add a jquery progress bar if you wanted.

Also tried tinymce but could not get it to upload images successfully.

Answer (score 1):

the filebrowser **does** have a progress-bar, check filebrowser3.